# Javascript JSON bad Output need other

Tags: javascript, json

Hello i want a json object without 2 quotes the current output is not valid.
How i can make this ?

I want exactly this:

```
{"format":{"id":"ivf","author":"","title":"","copyright":"","comment":"","album":"","year":"","track":"","genre":""}}
```

This is the Bad Output not Valid Json:

```
{"format":"{"id":"ivf","author":"","title":"","copyright":"","comment":"","album":"","year":"","track":"","genre":""}"}
```

video_format_serialized Data:

```
{"id":"ivf","author":"","title":"","copyright":"","comment":"","album":"","year":"","track":"","genre":""}

video_format_serialized = JSON.stringify($('#addprofile_FORM_video_format').serializeObject());
alert(video_format_serialized);
var format_object = {
    format:video_format_serialized
};
console.log(format_object);
var string = JSON.stringify(format_object);
tring.substring(1);
string.substring(0, string.length-1);
console.log(string);
string = string.replace(/\\/g, "");
console.log(string);
```

**UPDATE**
Here is the right code to make valid output.

```
var format_object = {
    format:$('#addprofile_FORM_video_format').serializeObject()
};
console.log(format_object);
var string = JSON.stringify(format_object);
string.substring(1);
string.substring(0, string.length-1);
console.log(string);
string = string.replace(/\\/g, "");
console.log(string);
```

Comment: im not sure what the question is...do you need to convert the second to the first?

Comment: on the second bad output json object you find 2 double quotes that need to be removed but JSON.stringify does nothing on the output

Answer (score 1):

You should use `JSON.stringify` on an object literal (not on a string, which is what I think you are doing) to create json -- that way you know it will be valid.  For example, if you have

`var toConvert = {format: {id: "ivf", "author": ""}};`

and you type

`JSON.stringify(toConvert);`

you will get

`"{"format":{"id":"ivf","author":""}}"`

Comment: i need without first quote and end quote

Comment: my point is if you use `stringify` on an object literal, you don't need to worry ...

Comment: Note that this isn't supported without a shim in IE7-